# Stop consumption of message for rabbitmq for a period of time

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-rabbit

Calling the stop method of SimpleMessageListenerContainer class is closing the channel ("Closing channel for unresponsive consumer"). But I don't want to close the channel. I am trying to stop the consumption of messages for a period of time and after some time I want to resume consumption of the message. Can anyone please suggest to me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be stopping the container from the listener thread - that causes a deadlock.

Call the stop on another thread.

```
someTaskExecutor.execute(() -> container.stop());
```

This will free up the listener thread.

Comment: It looks like he's saying is does the container have a pause mechanism because calling ```stop``` would close the channel which he doesn't want to.

Comment: The channel is always closed when you stop the container. Stopping it asynchronously avoids the log message. A new channel is used when restarting.